# Forcing ActionLinks to be rendered as lowercase

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Without creating my own ActionLink HtmlHelper is there a way to force any ActionLinks to be rendered lowercase?

**Update:**
Check out the following links for extending the RouteCollection to add LowecaseRoutes
<strike>[http://www.makiwa.com/index.php/2008/05/31/lowercase-mvc-route-urls/]</strike>
<strike>[http://goneale.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/]</strike>

**Update - 02/03/2011:**
Since the two links above now nolonger work, i'd made a post a while back with my solution

http://blog.lukesmith.net/2009/02/01/generating-and-enforcing-that-any-link-and-request-is-lowercase-with-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: FYI, the links in the question are dead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to handle this, is at the routing level. Force all route paths to be lowercase, and it will properly propagate to your action links etc.

The way I've solved this, is to create a new route class that inherits `Route` and simply overrides the `GetVirtualPath` method;

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    var virtualPath = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

    if (virtualPath != null)
        virtualPath.VirtualPath = virtualPath.VirtualPath.ToLowerInvariant();

    return virtualPath;
}
```

I've also created a few extension methods for `RouteCollection` to make it easy to use this new route class.