# Alter generated URLs in MVC globally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, seo

I have a very simple question.

I just want to be able to change every URL that gets create by a helper class in MVC.NET, the problem is that I don't know what I have to override to do so.

Edit: My goal is to change the behaviour of MVC when it does create urls..I want to make the urls which MVC creates seo friendly.

After hours of Google & Bing I am not much smarter...

If anyone knows where I have to change something, please give me a hint, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace yourbelovedNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides properties and methods for defining a seo friendly route
    /// </summary>
    public class SeoFriendlyRoute : Route
    {
        #region Constructors

        public SeoFriendlyRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
            : base(url, routeHandler)
        {
        }

        public SeoFriendlyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
            : base(url, defaults, routeHandler)
        {
        }

        public SeoFriendlyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints,
                                IRouteHandler routeHandler)
            : base(url, defaults, constraints, routeHandler)
        {
        }

        public SeoFriendlyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints,
                                RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
            : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler)
        {
        }

        #endregion

        public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            RouteData data = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
            return data;
        }

        public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            var trimmedValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (value.Value != null && value.Key != "controller" && value.Key != "action")
                    trimmedValues.Add(value.Key, GenerateSeourl(value.Value.ToString()));
                else
                {
                    trimmedValues.Add(value.Key, value.Value != null ? value.Value.ToString() : value.Value);
                }

            }
            VirtualPathData data = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, trimmedValues);
            if (data != null)
                data.VirtualPath = data.VirtualPath;
            return data;
        }

        private static string GenerateSeourl(string url)
        {
            // make the url lowercase
            var encodedUrl = (url ?? "");
            encodedUrl = encodedUrl
                .Replace("%20", "")
                .Replace(" ", "")
                .Replace("/", "-");
            return encodedUrl;
        }
    }

    public static class SeoFriendlyRouteCollectionExtensions
    {
        //Override for localized route
        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults)
        {
            return routes.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, defaults, null, null);
        }

        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults,
                                                object constraints)
        {
            return routes.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, null);
        }

        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults,
                                                object constraints, string[] namespaces)
        {
            if (routes == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
            }
            if (url == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
            }
            var item = new SeoFriendlyRoute(url, new MvcRouteHandler())
                           {
                               Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
                               Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),
                               DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
                           };
            if ((namespaces != null) && (namespaces.Length > 0))
            {
                item.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;
            }
            routes.Add(name, item);
            return item;
            //return routes.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, urlPattern, defaults, null);
        }

        private static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url,
                                                 object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
        {
            if ((namespaces == null) && (context.Namespaces != null))
            {
                namespaces = context.Namespaces.ToArray();
            }

            Route route = context.Routes.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, namespaces);
            route.DataTokens["area"] = context.AreaName;
            bool flag = (namespaces == null) || (namespaces.Length == 0);
            route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = flag;
            return route;
        }

        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url,
                                                object defaults, string[] namespaces)
        {
            return context.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, defaults, null, namespaces);
        }

        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url,
                                                object defaults, object constraints)
        {
            return context.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, null);
        }

        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url,
                                                string[] namespaces)
        {
            return context.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, null, namespaces);
        }

        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url,
                                                object defaults)
        {
            return context.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, defaults, null);
        }

        public static Route MapSeoFriendlyRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url)
        {
            return context.MapSeoFriendlyRoute(name, url, null);
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my solution for my problem. It allows to register "SEO" Routes in Areas AND the default RouteConfig.

The trimming process is not very mature but it was just for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Get to grips with routing:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Routes are found in the Global.asax file and HtmlHelpers like `ActionLink` should automatically adapt to your custom routes. If you specify a custom route above the default route and then do the following, the URL produced will match the route:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go!", "AnAction", "AController")
```

If you specify other parameters in your route that are not available as parameters to standard overloads of `ActionLink`, you can pass these in the `routeValues` parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go!", "AnAction", "AController",
    new { MyCustomParameter = "Hello" })
```

Comment: Hi, thank you...I know how routes work. My goal is to change the urls which get created to SEO friendly urls...i don't want to do this for ever url I generate so I am searching for a way to change the behavior how MVC creates urls from routes.

Comment: Well, your routes ARE your URLs, so there's no real way of achieving this as such with routing. You haven't specified any examples, but assuming you have a common pattern, the proper way of handling this is with URL rewriting: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: As i understand MVC will go trough your routecollection until it can match a route with the given parameters. Then it will create a url for the found route. Here I would like to change the behaviour of the system.

Comment: Anyway maybe the solution with IIS url rewriting will fit our needs, thank you.

Comment: You *could* change the behaviour of how it writes the links, but then the links won't match the routes when they're clicked, so all of your routes will be broken. URL rewriting is the best approach for what you want.

Comment: They still can match the routes...they would just be all lowercase and and without spaces....that's what I want...anyway url rewriting seems also to prevent wrong written urls from the user so it's better anyway.

Comment: It helps for error handling but it doesn't solve our problem for SEO friendly URLs as the crawler still sees the "bad" URL and not the one which has been rewritten from IIS

Comment: In this case you'll probably want to look at something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/495332/1043198

Comment: Thank you, I have developed a solution for us.